# How to delete all RSS feeds in IE at once?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, rss, feed

I'm using Windows 7, IE8. Over the time, I've added many RSS feeds to IE. I now want to delete all of them at once and start over.

Is there a quick and easy way to accomplish that? I hate having to delete one feed at a time through the UI, especially when I have hundreds of feeds.

Answer (score 2):

In IE7 & IE8, just delete the contents of :

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Feeds
```

which is normally the same as :

```
C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Feeds
```